# Caffe Classifier

Tags: python, classification, caffe

I looked around but I don't think the already raised questions can treat my problem.

I am having a problem with a function in caffe : Classifier. The code is bugging in this line :

```
net = caffe.Classifier(VGGmodel,VGGweights)
```

and I get the following (extract from the last lines) :

```
I0302 18:56:55.906224  4740 net.cpp:219] relu1_1 does not need backward computation.
I0302 18:56:55.906229  4740 net.cpp:219] conv1_1 does not need backward computation.
I0302 18:56:55.906231  4740 net.cpp:219] input does not need backward computation.
I0302 18:56:55.906236  4740 net.cpp:261] This network produces output pool5
I0302 18:56:55.906252  4740 net.cpp:274] Network initialization done.
I0302 18:56:56.754776  4740 upgrade_proto.cpp:51] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated V1LayerParameter: /home/mkammoun/PycharmProjects/Deep_Texture_2/Models/VGG_normalised.caffemodel
I0302 18:56:56.838132  4740 upgrade_proto.cpp:59] Successfully upgraded file specified using deprecated V1LayerParameter
I0302 18:56:56.838918  4740 upgrade_proto.cpp:65] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated input fields: /home/mkammoun/PycharmProjects/Deep_Texture_2/Models/VGG_normalised.caffemodel

Process finished with exit code 139
```

Anyone can help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Process finished with exit code 139

It means that process received signal 11 which means `SIGSEGV`
I had some experience with Caffe. It has no any normal error reporting and segfaults on any error.
You can use some debugger like `gdb` to find out where error occurs

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real solution, it just worked in my case. And it only works in my development env. If anyone has some ideas why this works, please don't hesitate to comment/answer.

It could be a memory problem. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704040/exit-code-139-when-perfroming-image-subtraction/34146379#34146379) got me on that track.) Caffe is very memory intensive, naturally. But it could be something else as well, e.g. in my case a problem with the data layer I'm using.

The "solution":

1. run in pycharm (or other dev env?), set a breakpoint at the net creation line (it does not work with pdb breakpoints). It also seemed to help to switch to Console view before the call to caffe.Net().
2. get rid of as many layers as possible (for me, removing one unnecessary data layer did the trick - BUT I believe I had bigger nets running already).

In my case, it only failed sometimes at first. When running it in pycharm and stopping at and after net creation, it worked most of the time. (sleep()'s didn't seem to help.) Then I changed the net, and it always segfaulted (139, as vitalii said).

Maybe using valgrind to track down the problem would be best (if you know how).

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the model specification prototype file. You are trying to import a caffe model that used deprecated prototype specifications for training. You can modify the net.cpp file in src folder to remove these warnings. It's just telling you that the upgrading from the old caffe model to the current caffe model you are using, failed. You should be good to go with small modification in the net.cpp file.