# Tkinter askopendialog runtime error after dialog confirmation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, runtime-error

Consider the following code snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

def mycallback(event):
    fname = fd.askopenfilename()
    print(fname)   

root = Tk()
b1 = Button(root, text='Hello!')
b1.bind('<Button-1>', mycallback)
b1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

After pressing the button b1 an open-dialog appears as supposed. If I press OK or CANCEL after choosing a file, the program crashes with exit code 139.

What's the problem here?

I'm using Python 3.4 on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem here (Python 2.7, win XP). Exit code 139 appears to be due to a [segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21661627/3714930). Also, just out of curiosity, why do you bind `<Button-1>` to b1 and not just use `b1 = Button(root, text='Hello!', command=mycallback)`?

Comment: That is because these are my very first steps in Tkinter. Your suggestion, however, works perfectly. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a function when clicking a button can be done using the button's `callback` argument.
So instead of binding `<Button-1>` to the button you should use

```
b1 = Button(root, text='Hello!', command=mycallback)
```

You should then also remove the event argument from the mycallback function, since command doesn't pass any arguments.

How this solves your problem, I really dont know. But according to your comment it does.

For more information on the Button (and any other) widget, see [effbot.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20201113224807/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)